How do I remove this green X from my QGIS?
When processing in QGIS, this green X appeared at the coordinates 0º latitude and 0º longitude. What does this mean?  And how can I remove it?
I tried to solve it using the display settings, but I couldn't find the option to deactivate it. It seems to be a bug.
